# Container error with exit code 134 while writing Parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I'm reading 8 million rows from a source and trying to enrich columns and store data to `HDFS.`
For enrichment, I need to left join the above table with again 4 tables.
Source table has data encrypted, so I wrote a `HIVE` function to decrypt the data of a column which becomes the joining criteria for other 4 tables.
All the 4 tables has the same column in encrypted form, So before joining I am decrypting these table column.

Issue:

While joining any two tables I am getting `Container error` issue

Steps I did:

1. Read source data and wrote it to Parquet format. Repartitoned the data.
2. Created a `Temp` view on the above data which I am using in queries

Running config:

- Driver Memory 45 GB
- executor memory - 50GB
- Executor core - 5
- No. of Executor - 15.

Kindly someone please help me suggesting the ways to load this data. Also how to avoid this container issue.

Comment: It just says, that executor quit with an error status. Executor logs will have the actual error.

Comment: @Dima. Any suggestions to approach the problem

Comment: can you see the application log and/or the container log ?

Comment: @VnS yes: look at the executor log, and see what the error was :)

Comment: @Dima Log only shows container issue. Posting Log above

Comment: @VnS that's the _driver_ log. You want the _executor_ log from the executor that failed.